# In reactjs when i use state to change my button color it works but not first click how to resolve this

Tags: css, reactjs, button, react-hooks, background-color

i have a button which used to route.The routes are from api so on my first click the route is working but the button color is not changing

i used useState hook and css  for changing the color,it is working perfectly but not on first click

Comment: post code for a minimum reproducible example :)

Comment: Can you please provide some code or snippet to understand/debug the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

If you project is created using CRA - create react app, you can add `activeclassname="active"` to your div and in css/scss file add wanted styling.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

<NavLink to="/some-route" activeclassname="active">
  text
</NavLink>

 & a {
   color: red
   &.active {
      color: blue;
   }
}
```

If you project is created using Vite, then you don't need activeclassname and only add:

```
<NavLink to="/some-route">text</NavLink >

 &.active {
    color: $blue;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the button color is not changing on the first click, because the state update is not happening in time to reflect the change in color. This can happen if the state update is asynchronous.

To ensure that the state update happens immediately, you can use the useEffect hook in combination with the useState hook.